# Testing for identical response

Tags: hypothesis-testing, references

In a recent task at my job I have come with a situation I cannot find references to research made about it. Basically, I have two procedures and I want to test if they behave exactly the same way (i.e., they will always give the same response when fed with the same input).

More precisely, say I have procedure 1 which, when fed with an input, will give a sequence as a response, say *ABAAB*. This procedure is the industry standard, but it is expensive.

Now, there is a (cheaper) proposed procedure 2 which should behave exactly the same way. So, if for three consecutive and (maybe) dependent inputs procedure 1 outputs *ABCAA*, *ACAAB* and *CABBA*; I should see the same three sequences as output from procedure 2.

Lets call $X_n$ the Bernoulli variable which equals 1 if both procedures give the same answer and 0 otherwise. So $X_n \sim Ber(p)$ and my null hypothesis is $p = 1$.

I cannot figure how to test this hypothesis with a finite sample. I can easily propose tests for the hypothesis $p > 1 - \epsilon$, but I would like to check if there is some work done regarding the original problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: An obvious rejection rule is to reject as soon as you see *any difference whatever* between the two sets of results. If the null is true, you will never reject, so the type I error rate is 0, the lowest it can be, but if the null is false, you will expect some difference to pop up eventually, so a large sample should often have excellent power (we can't say what it is without more information, though)

Comment: @glen_b Thank you for your comment. I know that as soon as I see some $X_m = 0$ then $H_0$ is to be rejected. But I have a finite sample (say a couple of thousand inputs) so my question is what confidence do I have with this test. Because if I see all the two thousands realizations equal one, under the alternative hypothesis the probability of this outcome is arbitrarily close to one if $p = 1 - \epsilon$ and $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small.

Comment: Just as I explained when discussing power above, we can't do anything specific (like derive a 5% test say) with the present information; you mention the possibility of dependence but we don't know anything about the form or the extent of it.

Comment: @glen_b Thank you again for your comment. I thought this was the situation (nothing more specific can be done unless more information is addedd) but it was worth asking in case it was not and I was unaware of it. I guess my best chances are to production department to give me more specific hypothesis to work with. Thanks again!